# Type mismatch with nullable and optional types

Tags: kotlin

I am researching Kotlin and Spring. I have started with basics. Creating simple CRUD app and experimenting on it.

I have these entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
class Article(


        var title: String,
        var headline: String,
        var content: String,
        @ManyToOne var author: User? = null,
        var addedAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
        var slug: String = title.toSlug(),
        @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null)


@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
class User(
        var login: String,
        var firstname: String,
        var lastname: String,
        var description: String? = null,
        @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null)
```

I have these repositories:

```
interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    fun findByLogin(login: String): User?

    fun findByLastname(lastname: String): User?
}

interface ArticleRepository : CrudRepository<Article, Long> {
    fun findBySlug(slug: String): Article?
    fun findAllByOrderByAddedAtDesc(): Iterable<Article>
}
```

And my rest controller:

```
@PostMapping("user/{userId}/newarticle")
    fun createArticle(@RequestBody article: Article, @PathVariable userId: Long) {
        val user = userRepository.findById(userId) 
        article.author = user <-- Type Mismatch
        repository.save(article) 
        var stophere = "what"
    }
```

When I try to save article (rest controller), on this line **article.author = user**

I get the following error:

Type Mismatch:

Required: User?

Found: Optional

I tried finding the solution, I think its regarding the Nullable values, but I cant figure it out.
It seems that Spring returns Java optional, while Kotlin does not need it.

Comment: `findById(userId)` What does this method return?

Comment: It returns user = {Optional@111} and inside it, there is another property named value that actually contains the user itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem.

I was using the Spring native `findById(userId)` which returns Optional type. Which is not compatible with Kotlin type.

I should have used the Kotlin's `userRepository.findByIdOrNull(userId)`.

More information can be found in [this](https://medium.com/@fatihcoskun/kotlin-nullable-types-vs-java-optional-988c50853692) excellent article.